# How to trigger and make sliding menu go back?

Tags: c#, wpf

Ive made a sliding menu out of examples online, There is two small detail i havent been able to understand and fix. I would like the menu to slide back again when pressing something in my menu. For example (ItemMain)

Now i have to press the button again to make it slide back (ButtonCloseMenu). I would like to have this feature left but also the option to slide it back automatic if ive pressed something in my ListViewMenu

Ive also tried to link a button outside my ListViewMenu to do the same as the menu bu that wont work.

Ive tried to trim the code so it will be as short as possible.

My MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OpenMenu">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridMenu">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="50"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.05" Value="200"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="CloseMenu">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridMenu">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="200"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="50"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="ButtonOpenMenu">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OpenMenu}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="ButtonCloseMenu">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CloseMenu}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>

<StackPanel>
    <Grid Height="50" Background="White" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonOpenMenu" Height="50" Width="50" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionMiniAccentButton}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#000000" Click="ButtonOpenMenu_Click">
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Menu" Width="25" Height="25"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonCloseMenu" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="50" Width="50" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionMiniAccentButton}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#000000" Click="ButtonCloseMenu_Click">
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ArrowLeft" Width="25" Height="25"/>
        </Button>
        <Image Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="ListViewMenu" Foreground="#FFFFFF" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="ListViewMenu_SelectionChanged">
        <ListViewItem x:Name="ItemMain" Height="40">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="House" Height="25" Width="25" Margin="5 0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Start" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

My MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void ButtonOpenMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ButtonCloseMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    ButtonOpenMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private void ButtonCloseMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ButtonCloseMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    ButtonOpenMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void ListViewMenu_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UserControl usc = null;
    GridMain.Children.Clear();

    switch (((ListViewItem)((ListView)sender).SelectedItem).Name)
    {
        case "ItemMain":
            usc = new UserControlMain();
            GridMain.Children.Add(usc);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the slide back action on the menu's `LostFocus` event.

Comment: LostFocus="ButtonCloseMenu_Click"  within the ListViewMenu? ive tried that and it will not get the result i want. My button for open and closing is bugging when i press it though.

Comment: No, there's a `WPF` event called `LostFocus` which is triggered when a control loses the focus.

Answer (score 1):

Let me illustrate the concept with a small sample code. Idea is this; upon clicking a button you display a bunch of text, which is analogous to you clicking the menu button in your application which slides out the menu. Then upon clicking elsewhere in the application, the previously displayed text is hidden, which is analogous to your menu sliding back.

```
<Window ...
        MouseDown="Window_MouseDown"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="400">
    <Grid Name="GridMain" Focusable="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Name="BtnShow" Grid.Row="0" Width="100" Height="32"
                Content="SHOW"
                Click="Button_Click" LostFocus="Button_LostFocus"/>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="CadetBlue"
                Width="200" Height="100">
            <TextBlock Name="TxtDisplay" Text="SOME TEXT"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Visibility="Hidden"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see I have a button and a text bloc in my application. You can see that there are two events attached to the button, one is the `Click` event that is triggered when clicking the button, and the second is the `LostFocus` which is triggered when the button loses focus. However note a couple other things:

- The window has a `MouseDown` event
- The outermost `Grid` has the `Focusable` property set to `true`.

This is because, a button (or any control) in `WPF` won't lose focus if you click on somewhere on the `Form`. To get around this, we attach the `MouseDown` even to the `Window`, then at the event handler, we're going to 'focus' on the grid. To do this we need to enable the previously mentioned property to true. Then when the grid is focused, you can't see any noticeable changes, but that does cause the button to fire the `LostFocus` even which is our desirable behavior. Finally, in the button's `LostFocus` event handler we do the action that simulates your menu sliding back, in this case simply hiding the text.

So the code behind looks like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TxtDisplay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void Button_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TxtDisplay.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        GridMain.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about the begin storeyboard in my case, how to connect that since thats the one that control the automation?